# How does the "if block" work in this code?

Tags: c++

Please consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    int a, b;
    cout << "Enter two integer: ";
    cin >> a >> b;

    if (a > b) {
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    cout << a << "<=" << b << endl;
}
```

The above code yields the minimum of the two inserted numbers. Can anyone explain how the if block works?

Comment: I generally don't get the a=b and b=temp. What do these two lines do?

Comment: Have you ever carried a heavy thing in each hand and you exchange the things in your hands by temporarily putting down just one of them so you can change hand for the other heavy thing without putting it down, and then you pick up the first thing again? It's exactly that.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Does XOR swap correspond to juggling?

Comment: For learning C++, you'll find one of these [good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to be very helpful.

Comment: In general, you'd probably want to use [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) instead..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the idiomatic way of swapping two numbers.

There are more efficient ways: to exploit those use `std::swap` instead.

(The statement `int temp=a;` sets the variable `temp` to the value of `a`. The statement `a=b;` sets `a` to the value of `b`. Finally, `b=temp;` sets `b` to `temp` which was the original value of `a`. The overall effect therefore is to exchange the values of `a` and `b`.)

Comment: Thanks but can you please let me know what you mean by swapping numbers. I am just learning the basics of C++.

Comment: Can you please explain how this exchange of values is related to finding out the minimum.

Comment: Because the exchange only happens if `a` is larger than `b`.